# Illegal Start of Expression with Method

Tags: java, arrays

So I am trying to open/close/reopen/read and array into a 1 dimensional array and a 2 dimensional array.

```
public class Assigntment2Condensed
{
   public static void main (String[] args) throws IOException
   {

//Creating the menu options

      System.out.println("\n\nPlease choose an option below\n"
                          + "\tA. Read Data\n"
                          + "\tB. Modify Data\n"
                          + "\tC. Clear Data\n"
                          + "\tD. Display Data\n"
                          + "\tE. Save Data to a file\n"
                          + "\tF. Quit");
      System.out.print("\n=> ");                   
      //WHAT I NEED: While loop and a nested If statement

      //getting user input:: can create a method
      String input = keyboard.nextLine();      
      input = input.toUpperCase();     //what the user inputs will be made to an upper case char
      char charInput = input.charAt(0);   //gets the character in the 0 position

       //main methods
      int[][] originalMap = getMap(new Scanner(new File("map.dat")));  //reads data into the array :: Menu Option A
      getShowArray(originalMap); //passing contents of original map into the method :: Menu Option D
      getWriteArray(modifiedMap); //method created to write the contents of the modified map to a file. :: Menu Option B

// Method classes     
//Read in array from file to a two dimen. array. returns array Map. :: Menu Option A
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
   {  
      int index = 0;
      String map;

      Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

      System.out.println("\n\nOpening 'map.dat' file and adding elements to the array....\n");

      //open the file
      File file = new File("map.dat");

      Scanner openFile = new Scanner(file);    //reads in the file into the openFile instance

      //read the file contents
      while(openFile.hasNext())
      { 
         map = openFile.nextLine();

         //System.out.println(map);
         index++;

      }
      openFile.close();

      //read contents into an array

      File map2 = new File("map.dat");
      Scanner openFile2 = new Scanner(map2);

      int[] numArray = new int[index]; //creates Array
      for(int i = 0; i < numArray.length; i++)
      {
         numArray[i] = openFile2.nextInt();
         //System.out.print(numArray[i] + " " );

      }          



   //-=-===-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-==-=
      int rows = file.nextInt();
      int columns = file.nextInt();

      int[][] map = new int[rows][columns];

      for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
      {
         for(int j = 0; j < columns; j++)
         {
            map[i][j] = file.nextInt();
            System.out.print(map[i][j] + "  ");
         }
         System.out.println("");
      }

      file.close();

      return map;
   }

//displaying the array when called :: Menu Option D
   private static void getShowArray(int[][] originalMap)
   {
      for (int row = 0; row < originalMap.length; row++)
      {
         for(int col = 0; col < originalMap.length; col++)
            System.out.print(originalMap[row][col] + " | ");
         System.out.println();
      }
   }

//writing modifiedMap array to a txt file :: Menu Option B
   public static void getWriteArray(int[][] modifiedMap)
   {
      dataInputStream inputFile = new DataInputStream(new fileInputStream("map.dat"));
      System.out.println("\nWriting to the 'map.dat' file...");

      //write to binary file
      for (int i = 0; i < modifiedMap.length; i++)
         outputFile.writeInt(modifiedMap[i]);

      //close file
      outputFile.close();
      System.out.println("Done.");
   }


}
```

I am getting the error:

```
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: illegal start of expression
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
   ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: illegal start of expression
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
          ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: ';' expected
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
                ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: illegal start of expression
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
                    ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: ';' expected
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
                     ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: illegal start of expression
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
                      ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: ';' expected
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
                       ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: ')' expected
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
                                       ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: illegal start of expression
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
                                            ^
Assigntment2Condensed.java:30: error: ';' expected
   public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)
                                             ^
10 errors
```

The "=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-" is an indication of that the code prior to that line was previously outside of that method and anything below that was already working in that method. I need to create a menu option so when they click A the file is read into the program.

Comment: Please do not dump your whole code like this onto Stack Overflow... Read the [help] and [mcve]. For starters, you're missing a curly brace to end the `main` method.

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a method inside a method.  The compiler thinks that `public static int[][] getMap(Scanner file)` is inside your main method, and it's probably not what you're after.